# Why do I get this error (Cannot read from the source file or disk) when trying to move a folder and its files from a document library on one My Site to another My Site?

Tags: sharepoint, filesystems, sharepoint-2007

I am trying to do the transfer in Windows Explorer and have full control on both My Sites.

Thanks very much for your help.

I also asked the question on an: [MSDN Sharepoint forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsocialcomputing/thread/66f365eb-dba2-44c1-ac4a-ec065aed71f8)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe Explorer can handle copying from one remote location to another.  Try copying it to your local system, and then from your local system to the other Sharepoint server.

Comment: Yeah, explorer will do this but in my experience I tend to terminal into either of the boxes and do it there...

Answer (score 0):

You might have 'Full Control' but do any of the groups you belong to have the 'Deny' right? If they do, then you will be denied access anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the lenght of the file name you are trying to move. Rename the file and move it

Answer (score 0):

agree with the answer above me, best bet is to ever use a download upload manager such as filezilla (http://filezilla-project.org/) to grab the files and then upload to your other remote location.

if your still having problems then connection speed, number of connections and permissions may also need to be looked in to from the server your uploading from, and assuming that this is from hosting company such as godaddy for example.

Comment: There's no answer above you in my view.  Might be a good idea to reference the answerer, or link to the answer you're talking about in the future.  Or leave that kind of response to answer comments, for that matter.